Netlify & Vercel Blank Page with create-react-app
I’ve deployed my backend on Render.com, but I'm having issues getting my frontend to work on both Vercel and Netlify. The latest attempt was with Netlify, but I encountered the same problem.
I'm using Vite with the Create React App command to build my app, along with React Router for client-side routing and Axios for making API requests to Render.com. Below are my package.json and file structure for reference:
[package.json]
[structure]
THIS IS MY GITHUB REPO:
https://github.com/codingcreedd/messagingAppTOP
I tried adding "homepage": ".", "" and "./" but none of them worked. I tried using CI=false as an environment variable in netlify and in my package.json but it also failed. I also tried creating a _redirects file in the public directory, but nothing worked.
import { defineConfig } from "vite"; 
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    base: "https://whatsuptop.netlify.app/src/main.jsx",
});

this is my vite.config.js file as well if it helps

I don't know how exactly it worked, but I woke up today and it was working, here are the things I have:
1- "homepage": "." in my package.json
2- Adding CI=false to the build command, ex: "CI=false vite build"
3- Creating a _redirects file in the public directory with the following content:
/*    /index.html   200

4- Changed my vite.config.js as follows:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";



// https://vitejs.dev/config/
   export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      base: "/",
   });

   Make sure the base is / not ./ for loading the page on refresh as well. When I put it "./", the page was not blank on the first load but it was becoming blank whenever I refresh

5- Added netlify.toml file with the following content:
    [[redirects]]
       from = "/*"
       to = "/index.html"
       status = 200

